# Eclipse The hierarchy of type VerificationTokenRepository is inconsistent

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following project structure:

```
P - Parent Module
A - Module A with parent P 
B - Module B with parent P and depends on A (no module-info)
```

In module A I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IRepository<T, K extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, K>
public interface IIdRepository<T> extends IRepository<T, Long> {/* */}
public interface ITokenRepository<T extends AbstractToken> extends IIdRepository<T>
```

and in Module B I have the following interface:

```
public interface VerificationTokenRepository<T extends VerificationToken> extends ITokenRepository<T>{
```

This last interface is the one that gets the subject message. None of the interfaces in Module A cause any errors. All the dependencies in the pom for Module A exist in the pom for Module B and Module B has Module A as a dependency. If I change the definition fo VerificationTokenRegistry so that it extends each of the other interfaces, I still get the same error. If it extends JpaRepository I get no error. I have cleaned, installed, and deployed each of the dependencies. I have restarted Eclipse. But that doesn't help.

Additionally, the error occurs only in the editor window. It does not appear in the Problem window, the Marker window and is not flagged in the Package Explorer window.

The error occurs in the same way for all the interfaces defined in Module B which extend interfaces in Module A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that one way to bypass the problem is to separate the offending code into a separate module. The validation module doesn't seem to have a problem if that is done. I assume that is because the amount of code in the module is small.